# Can I adjust the PS4 button on my controller?

Tags: controllers, ps4

I just started playing Injustice Gods Among Us.  While performing the moves  with the left stick my thumb is frequently hitting the PS button which pulls me back to the Play Station home screen on my PS4.  Which is not cool.  I guess my hands are too big.
Is there any way to adjust the PS button to require a longer press, or disable it?  I know push and hold brings up the logoff/shutdown menu.

Comment: I solved my specific situation by using the d-pad instead of the left analog stick.

Comment: That would've been my suggestions. The stick is far too slow for fighting game inputs. D-Pad is where it's at for NRS fighters.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to remap controls via the Button Assignments section within Accessibility settings.  The PS button is not mappable, but the other ones are.

https://www.howtogeek.com/245977/how-to-remap-buttons-on-your-playstation-4s-controller/